# What is the best practice to handle event with order?

Tags: algorithm, events

When you play card games, you always face some abilities and effects will be triggered at the same time. To resolve this, players relies on the rules. For example, if a minion dies, it triggers effects on my side and opponent side. If the effects is handled on my side first if it is my turn.

But how would you resolve it in computer games. Even you are using mediator for event handling, the event is usually handled by the order of subscription. Unless there are some indicators for the subscribers, you will not able to distinguish between the subscribers. But wouldn't it defeats the purpose of observer pattern? What is the best way implement it?

Comment: Are you asking how to decide what event should be handled first or how to handle two events as if they occurred simultaneously (at the same time)?

Comment: @Charanor Not really. I am asking if there are multiple listeners to one event. How can I handle the ordering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending a clarifying edit to your original question, I assume the following:

1. The game implements the [observer behavioral design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) using some base`TableObserver` class from which `Player` inherits.
2. Some `TableTop` class exists that subscribes, unsubscribes, and notifies its vector of `TableObserver` references.
3. Each `Player` submits actions to an instance of `TableTop` for processing *in turns*, for example `table.SubmitAction( playerOne, action );`
4. The `TableTop` instance resolves all submitted actions **after** a round of `Player` action submissions.

Wherein `table.SubmitAction( playerOne, action );`:

- `table` is an instance of `class TableTop` which is either globally visible, or that each player has a reference to.
- `SubmitAction` is a `public` member function of `class TableTop`
- `playerOne` is an instance of `class Player` (which inherits from `TableObserver`)
- `action` is either an instance of `class PlayerAction`, or some other arbitrary argument such as a `std::string` like `"floop the pig"`

---

### Option 1

Start a **globally visible timer** at the beginning of the game that continuously counts up using an `unsigned` 32-bit value.

Then, either modify `TableTop`'s `SubmitAction` function to take an additional game-time-stamp `table.SubmitAction( playerOne, action, gameTime );`, or have `TableTop` internally cache the game-time during `SubmitAction` execution.

After the `TableTop` instance processes all the submitted actions for a round of play, it can **sort** its list of `TableObserver` references in order of submission time-stamps. Finally, the `TableTop` can iterate over the newly sorted list of `TableObserver` references.

---

The same time-stamping idea could also be applied during the `TableObserver` notification process:

Either `TableTop` can send the game-time-stamp as `observer.notify(notificationTime)`, or `TableObserver` can internally cache the game-time during `notify` execution. Both require that the `TableObserver` class have an `unsigned` 32-bit `notifiedTime` variable.

A `Player` can then use `notifiedTime` for whatever duration/delay calculations it may need.

---

### Option 2

Forget the **round of play before resolution** mechanic, and replace the overly-specific base observer class `TableObserver` with the general `Observer`.

Assume there is a `MinionCard` class, that inherits from a`Card` class which can subscribe, unsubscribe, and notify instances of `Observer` (for example a `Player`), as before.

If an instance of `MinionCard` has its `health` drop below 0, then -- as-per your question's initial example -- it would need to notify the `Player` whose turn it currently is, *then* any other players that event may affect.

This can be accomplished by giving the base `Observer` class an internal `priority` value, which is updated either each turn, or updated based on some other rule such as physical proximity of `Player` instances.

For example, the `Player` whose turn it is always has `priority == 1`, and the remaining `Player`s' priorities are calculated by the square of the distance between the `Player` with `priority == 1`, hence increasing with range.

This `priority` updating can either be handled by each `Player` instance internally, or more simply by a `PlayerManager` class or some other such object that tracks all the players on a moment-to-moment basis.

Now, going back to `MinionCard`'s death, *before* it begins it iteration over its vector of `Observer` references, it can **sort** that vector based on `Observer` `priority`.

For example, using C++'s STL:

```
std::sort( observerList.begin(), 
           observerList.end(), 
           [] (auto && a, auto && b) { 
               return a.priority < b.priority; 
           } 
);
for ( Observer & observer : observerList ) {
    observer.notify();
}
```

---

The overall idea is to sort the `Observer` references before notifying them. I hope that helps. Again, SE is more useful if questions are as specific as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I would use global counter or timestamp on event delivery and process them by this ordered.